# Difficult issue to troubleshoot with Gate and Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have been trying to solve this issue for days, but I struggle.
I tried to pack this post with as many information as I could because it is not easy to troubleshoot.

```
        "laravel/framework": "9.41.0",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "5.7"
```

**Explanation**
If I drag any rows with the admin role, it works perfectly.
If I drag a role with the manager role, the first drag works, on the second drag I get this:

**Unknown named parameter $id**      <---THIS IS THE ERROR

Routes:

```
require __DIR__ . '/auth.php';

Route::prefix('/')
    ->middleware(['auth','verified'])
    ->group(function () {
        Route::resource('roles', RoleController::class);
        Route::resource('permissions', PermissionController::class);
        Route::resource('users', UserController::class);
        Route::resource('popups', PopupController::class);
    });
```

```
Illuminate\ Auth\ Access \ Gate : 535 callAuthCallback


    /**

     * Resolve and call the appropriate authorization callback.

     *

     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null  $user

     * @param  string  $ability

     * @param  array  $arguments

     * @return bool

     */

    protected function callAuthCallback($user, $ability, array $arguments)

    {

        $callback = $this->resolveAuthCallback($user, $ability, $arguments);



        return $callback($user, ...$arguments); //This line shows in RED

    }
```

I using this library to drag and drop a table row:
https://github.com/nextapps-be/livewire-sortablejs

**This is my component:**

```
<table class="w-full max-w-full mb-4 bg-transparent">
    <thead class="text-gray-700">
    <tr>
        <th class="px-4 py-3 text-left"></th>
        <th class="px-4 py-3 text-left"></th>
        <th class="px-4 py-3 text-left"></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody wire:sortable="reorder" wire:sortable.options="{ animation: 100 }" class="text-gray-600">
    @forelse($popups as $popup)
        <tr wire:sortable.item="{{ $popup['id'] }}" wire:sortable.triggers="reorder" class="hover:bg-gray-50 {{ $popup['order'] === 1 ? 'bg-yellow-50' : '' }}" wire:key="popup-{{ $popup['id'] }}">
            <td class="px-4 py-3 text-left">
                {{ $popup['id'] ?? '-' }}
            </td>
            <td class="px-4 py-3 text-left">
                {{ $popup['title'] ?? '-' }}
            </td>
            <td class="px-4 py-3 text-left">
                {{ $popup['reset_popup_days'] ?? '-' }}
            </td>
            <td>
                <button wire:sortable.handle>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" className="w-6 h-6">
                        <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M8.25 15L12 18.75 15.75 15m-7.5-6L12 5.25 15.75 9"/>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @empty
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7">
                @lang('crud.common.no_items_found')
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforelse
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**The livewire class:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Table\Popup;

use App\Models\Popup;
use Livewire\Component;

class Index extends Component
{
    public $popups;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->popups = Popup::orderBy('order')->get();
    }


    public function reorder($reorderedIds)
    {

        $orderedIds = collect($reorderedIds)->sortBy('order')->pluck('value');
        $this->popups = $orderedIds->map(function ($id) {
            return collect($this->popups)->where('id', (int)$id)->first();
        })->values();

        foreach ($this->popups as $index => $popup) {
            $popup = Popup::find($popup['id']);
            $popup->order = $index + 1;
            $popup->save();
        }

    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.table.popup.index', ['popups' => $this->popups]);
    }
}
```

I am using Gates and Policies for the Laravel controllers(not using it on livewire components directly yet as I am not sure if I should).

This is my controller so when the user lands on the CRUD, he can access all the different pages.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Popup;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Http\Requests\PopupStoreRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\PopupUpdateRequest;

class PopupController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $this->authorize('view-any', Popup::class);

        $search = $request->get('search', '');

        $popups = Popup::search($search)
            ->latest()
            ->paginate(5)
            ->withQueryString();

        return view('app.popups.index', compact('popups', 'search'));
    }

    /**
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $this->authorize('create', Popup::class);

        return view('app.popups.create');
    }

    /**
     * @param \App\Http\Requests\PopupStoreRequest $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(PopupStoreRequest $request)
    {
        $this->authorize('create', Popup::class);

        $validated = $request->validated();
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $validated['image'] = $request->file('image')->store('public');
        }

        //$latestOrder = Popup::orderBy('order')->get()->last();
        $latestOrder = Popup::orderBy('order', 'desc')->first();
        $order = $latestOrder ? $latestOrder->order + 1 : 0;

        $popup = Popup::create(array_merge($validated, ['order' => $order]));
        //$popup = Popup::create($validated);

        return redirect()
            ->route('popups.edit', $popup)
            ->withSuccess(__('crud.common.created'));
    }

    /**
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \App\Models\Popup $popup
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Request $request, Popup $popup)
    {
        $this->authorize('view', $popup);

        return view('app.popups.show', compact('popup'));
    }

    /**
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \App\Models\Popup $popup
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, Popup $popup)
    {
        $this->authorize('update', $popup);

        return view('app.popups.edit', compact('popup'));
    }

    /**
     * @param \App\Http\Requests\PopupUpdateRequest $request
     * @param \App\Models\Popup $popup
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(PopupUpdateRequest $request, Popup $popup)
    {
        $this->authorize('update', $popup);

        $validated = $request->validated();
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            if ($popup->image) {
                Storage::delete($popup->image);
            }

            $validated['image'] = $request->file('image')->store('public');
        }

        $popup->update($validated);

        return redirect()
            ->route('popups.edit', $popup)
            ->withSuccess(__('crud.common.saved'));
    }

    /**
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \App\Models\Popup $popup
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Request $request, Popup $popup)
    {
        $this->authorize('delete', $popup);

        if ($popup->image) {
            Storage::delete($popup->image);
        }

        $popup->delete();

        return redirect()
            ->route('popups.index')
            ->withSuccess(__('crud.common.removed'));
    }
}
```

**My policies:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Popup;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class PopupPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the popup can view any models.
     *
     * @param  App\Models\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        return $user->hasPermissionTo('list popups');
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the popup can view the model.
     *
     * @param  App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  App\Models\Popup  $model
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function view(User $user, Popup $model)
    {
        return $user->hasPermissionTo('view popups');
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the popup can create models.
     *
     * @param  App\Models\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        return $user->hasPermissionTo('create popups');
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the popup can update the model.
     *
     * @param  App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  App\Models\Popup  $model
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function update(User $user, Popup $model)
    {
        return $user->hasPermissionTo('update popups');
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the popup can delete the model.
     *
     * @param  App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  App\Models\Popup  $model
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function delete(User $user, Popup $model)
    {
        return $user->hasPermissionTo('delete popups');
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can delete multiple instances of the model.
     *
     * @param  App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  App\Models\Popup  $model
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function deleteAny(User $user)
    {
        return $user->hasPermissionTo('delete popups');
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the popup can restore the model.
     *
     * @param  App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  App\Models\Popup  $model
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function restore(User $user, Popup $model)
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the popup can permanently delete the model.
     *
     * @param  App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  App\Models\Popup  $model
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function forceDelete(User $user, Popup $model)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**And the manager is assigned:**

```
        Permission::create(['name' => 'list popups']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'view popups']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'create popups']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'update popups']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'delete popups']);
```

While the admin is assigned all the permissions like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        // 'App\Models\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // Automatically finding the Policies
        Gate::guessPolicyNamesUsing(function ($modelClass) {
            return 'App\\Policies\\' . class_basename($modelClass) . 'Policy';
        });

        $this->registerPolicies();

        // Implicitly grant "Super Admin" role all permission checks using can()
        Gate::before(function ($user, $ability) {
            logger($ability);
            if ($user->isSuperAdmin()) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[TRIED]

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Table\Popup;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use App\Models\Popup;
use Livewire\Component;

class Index extends Component
{
    use AuthorizesRequests;

    public $popups;

    public function mount()
    {
        //$this->popups = Popup::orderBy('order')->get()->toArray();
        $this->popups = Popup::orderBy('order')->get();
    }


    public function reorder($reorderedIds)
    {
        $this->authorize('update', array($this->popups));
        $orderedIds = collect($reorderedIds)->sortBy('order')->pluck('value');
        $this->popups = $orderedIds->map(function ($id) {
            return collect($this->popups)->where('id', (int)$id)->first();
        })->values();

        //logger($this->popups);

        foreach ($this->popups as $index => $popup) {
            $popup = Popup::find($popup['id']);
            $popup->order = $index + 1;
            $popup->save();
        }

    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.table.popup.index', ['popups' => $this->popups]);
    }
}
```

But getting this:

```
403 THIS ACTION IS UNAUTHORIZED.

//Event with the action is authorised(I checked the database and it is 100% authorised.

I think array($this->popups) is causing the issue as the data is different from the controler update authorised method....But how can I solve this if both methods deal differently with the data. In the old controller the update was dealing with a $POST array, while $this->popups deals with a collection.
```

[SOLUTION]
The solution to the $id issue was a change in code in the livewire class:

```
$popupIds = collect($reorderedIds)->pluck('value'); $popups = Popup::whereIn('id', $popupIds) ->orderBy('order') ->get() ->mapWithKeys(function ($popup) { return [$popup->id => $popup]; }); $this->popups = collect($reorderedIds)->map(function ($item) use ($popups) { return $popups[$item['value']]; });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this issue is connected to [this PHP 8 modification](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params#call_user_func_and_friends) that makes string keys interpreted as function parameter names. So when the custom policy function is called with the argument unpacking (`...`) operator here:

```
return $callback($user, ...$arguments);
```

the `$popup` variable (which is behaving like an associative array) from e.g. `$this->authorize('update', $popup);` becomes the named arguments of the policy functions after the unpacking. However since the policy functions do not have an `$id` argument, they throw the error.

You can try to run the code with PHP 7 to confirm the source of the issue.

To fix this you can try to embed the extra arguments of `authorize()` in an array, so the first array unpacking will only deconstruct the outer array, so the `$popup` array remains intact:

```
$this->authorize('update', array($popup));
```

Or you can also remove the extra arguments of `authorize()` since you don't use them in the policy functions.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I added more data right at the bottom of my post. I think you are close to it, now my issue is that in the update method between the old update method and this livewire method, the data coming in is different: I think array($this->popups) is causing the issue as the data is different from the controller update authorised method....But how can I solve this if both methods deal differently with the updated data. In the old controller the update was dealing with a $POST array, while $this->popups deals with a collection.

Comment: Looking at your policy functions you have general permission roles, not element-level ones, I mean you do not check whether an user can access a specific popup, you are only checking whether an user has a general permission to update all popups. So one possible solution is to remove the `$this->popups` argument completely: `$this->authorize('update');` (and of course from the policy function as well).

Comment: A different solution to overcome the single vs. collection problem is to make a loop over the `$this->popups` collection and check the permission of the popups one by one. I suppose you don't have hundreds of popups at once, so the multiple `$this->authorize('update', array($just_one_popup_from_the_loop));` calls do not introduce a noticeable overhead. This way you can reuse the policy function written for the single input element case.

Comment: From the Policy I did this as you suggested:

     public function update(User $user)
    {
        return $user->hasPermissionTo('update');
    }


In the livewire class:

   public function mount()
    {
        $this->authorize('update');
        $this->popups = Popup::orderBy('order')->get();
       
    }


But get this on the second drag and drop in the livewire component:
403
THIS ACTION IS UNAUTHORIZED.

Sorry it seems that I cannot show you the code well formatted in this chat

Comment: To test this I added in the livewire class this:   $this->authorize('view-any', Popup::class);   I can now access the table, but, as soon as I drag and drop 1 row, I see this on the second try "Unknown named parameter $id" and points to this below:    protected function callAuthCallback($user, $ability, array $arguments)

    {

        $callback = $this->resolveAuthCallback($user, $ability, $arguments);



        return $callback($user, ...$arguments);

    }

Comment: It seems that during the ajax call of Livewire, an extra parameter is needed. But only on the second try, this is just weird.

Comment: And if you reload the page you can do a new drag-and-drop action again? Do you see the updated `order` values in the database?

Comment: Yes, as soon as I reload, I can drag and drop the rows again, first one, ok,second, requires an ID.

Comment: I also tried this from your above idea with the loop, same issue:         foreach ($this->popups as $index => $popup) {
            $this->authorize('update', $popup);
            $popup = Popup::find($popup['id']);
            $popup->order = $index + 1;
            $popup->save();
        }   but same problem....

Comment: For the admin, the problem does not happen because of this code:    Gate::before(function ($user, $ability) {
            logger($ability);
            if ($user->isSuperAdmin()) {
                return true;
            }
        });

I removed the code and the problem happened aswell for the admin, so for sure it is a Gate issue.

Comment: Found something! The first try, the $popup is an object, on the second it is an array....need to work out why now.

Comment: Great, you should add this solution (for the second issue) to your post, maybe others will find it useful, it's hard to spot it in the comments.

Comment: I will add it now :-)